# P90 performance goal on internal functions does not result in P90 performance metric on API. What should be the performance goal for sub-component?

Tags: performance, statistics, metrics

We are a transaction platform. We have a performance goal for our API end-point to deliver 90% of transactions within T seconds. Internally that API end-point uses 5 functions: A, B, C, D and E.

Each function call takes time. If the function A and B fail, they are retried 2 more time. If the function C fails, it is retried 3 more times. Function D and E are called within a loop such that the loop is run as per a parameter passed by the customer.

We want to set performance goals for those 5 function calls such that we ensure the perfomance goal is met for the API end point. We prefer to set the performance goals in this pattern: For function A: X% of function calls should finish within y seconds.

We analysed the data to find out the composition of time T. We identified the aspirational goal for each function call. We set 90%ile goal for each function.

Unfortunately, this is not simple. Let's assume all functions meet their goal. Each function call supports 90% transaction within their stipulated time frame. If those set of 90% sessions are common (same exact sessions) across all function, the goal will be met for API end-point.

However, that is practically never true. No function violates its own benchmark, but they can violate the benchmark in transactions which other functions are running fine on.